# HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Hibernate Session bound to thread

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, session, transactions

I write test spring application. I have problem.

**my java code:**

controller method

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/index")
    public String setupForm()
    {    
        mainService.getAllRecords());
    }
```

service interface

```
@Transactional
public interface MainService
{

    public List<Record> getAllRecords();
}
```

service impl

```
@Service("mainService")
@Transactional
public class MainServiceImpl implements MainService
{
    @Autowired
    private MainDao mainDao;


    @Transactional
    public List<Record> getAllRecords()
    {

        return mainDao.getAllRecords();
    }

}
```

dao doesn't mark as @Transactional.

I see next error:

```
HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Hibernate Session bound to thread, and configuration does not allow creation of non-transactional one here
```

If I mark dao interface as @Transactional   - it works good.

**Configuration:**

web.xml

```
<context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param> 

    <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Processes application requests -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

data.xml

```
<!-- Настраивает управление транзакциями с помощью аннотации @Transactional -->
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
    <!-- Менеджер транзакций -->
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="classpath:messages" />
        <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
    </bean>
    <!-- Настройки бина dataSource будем хранить в отдельном файле -->
    <bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer" p:location="/WEB-INF/jdbc.properties" />
    <!-- Непосредственно бин dataSource -->
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource" p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}"
        p:url="${jdbc.databaseurl}" p:username="${jdbc.username}" p:password="${jdbc.password}" />
    <!-- Настройки фабрики сессий Хибернейта -->
    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="configLocation">
            <value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
        </property>
        <property name="configurationClass">
            <value>org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration</value>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${jdbc.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.charSet">UTF-8</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

root-context.xml

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.wp.crud.dao"/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.wp.crud.controller"/>

<!--
 Файл с настройками ресурсов для работы с данными (Data Access Resources) 
-->
 <import resource="data.xml"/>
```

servlet-context.xml

```
<annotation-driven />

    <!-- Всю статику (изображения, css-файлы, javascript) положим в папку webapp/resources и замаппим их на урл вида /resources/** -->

    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
    <!-- Отображение видов на jsp-файлы, лежащие в папке /WEB-INF/views -->

    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>
    <!-- Файл с настройками контроллеров -->

    <beans:import resource="controllers.xml" />
```

controllers.xml

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.wp.crud.controller"/>
```

I don't understand cause of this problem.

can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your web.xml you are missing to declare Hibernate OpenSessionInViewFilter, that provides your hibernate session to be open within your request process:

```
<filter>
        <filter-name>hibernateFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>singleSession</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>hibernateFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

This should fix your error.
Please note that the filter class is for Hibernate4, you need to fix in case of Hibernate3

Comment: it is working advice. But I cannot understand what the problem was solved after addin this snippet to web.xml

Comment: OpenSessionInViewFilter is a web filter that opens an hibernate session anytime you make a request and bound it to your threadlocal. So in your dao you can always call sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()

Comment: seems, I saw examples with **@Transactional** and without this filter. Can it be true?

Comment: I have found my old project and there are I use hibernate+spring+transactional

Comment: i've always used this filter with hibernate.. so i don't know exactly how it works without it.. sorry..

Answer (score 0):

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.wp.crud.controller"/>
```

Do you really need this line in both `root-context.xml` and `controllers.xml`?

I think first you should replace (if not already replaced) `com.wp.crud.controller` in `root-context.xml` by your service package.

And also you should place these component scans somewhere after this line from `data.xml`:

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
```

so `@Transactional` annotation could have effect on scanned classes.

By the way, you don't need `@Transactional` on service interface.

Comment: usually i exclude controllers from root context, placing them into servlet context.

Comment: @EmanueleRighetto it's ok, but there are now two `component-scan`s for  controllers package and I can't see any for services

Comment: yep, u're right, i didn't noticed that one component scan is only picking up dao

Comment: Sorry, max. I know that it is bad But my controllers and services are located in same package.

Comment: @gstackoverflow so you made changes only in web.xml, an now it works?

Comment: Yes. if you want I can to give you this project.

Answer (score 0):

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager"/>
    <!-- Transaction Manager is defined -->
    <bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
</bean>
```

**Add this jar file in library**

aopalliance-1.0.jar