# hibernateFilter when I use @Transactional. It is necessarily?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, transactions

I research using transactional annotation in Spring + Hibernate application.

I had problem with using annotation.
I had so problem:

```
No Hibernate Session bound to thread
```

my partner to advice me use this filter in web.xml:

```
<filter>
        <filter-name>hibernateFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>singleSession</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>hibernateFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

after I made it problem was resolved. He said me that always when he uses `@Transactional` annotation he writes this filter.

But in my old application I found using `@Transactional` without this filter. And it is working application.

Who can explain me it?

application which doesn't work without filter described here:
[HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Hibernate Session bound to thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20299064/http-status-500-request-processing-failed-nested-exception-is-org-hibernate-h)

**update:**

model class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "RECORDS")
public class Record
{
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int recordId;
    @Column(name = "VALUE1")
    private String vol1;
    @Column(name = "VALUE2")
    private String vol2;
    @Column(name = "VALUE3")
    private String vol3;
    //////////
    get and set
```

}

**update**

trace:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [appServlet] in context with path [/crud] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Hibernate Session bound to thread, and configuration does not allow creation of non-transactional one here] with root cause
org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Hibernate Session bound to thread, and configuration does not allow creation of non-transactional one here
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SpringSessionContext.currentSession(SpringSessionContext.java:63)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:544)
    at com.wp.crud.dao.MainDaoImpl.getAllRecords(MainDaoImpl.java:49)
    at com.wp.crud.controller.MainServiceImpl.getAllRecords(MainServiceImpl.java:50)
    at com.wp.crud.controller.MainController.setupForm(MainController.java:26)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:213)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:126)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:96)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:617)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:578)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

**my java code:**

controller method

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/index")
    public String setupForm()
    {    
        mainService.getAllRecords());
    }
```

service interface

```
@Transactional
public interface MainService
{

    public List<Record> getAllRecords();
}
```

service impl

```
@Service("mainService")
@Transactional
public class MainServiceImpl implements MainService
{
    @Autowired
    private MainDao mainDao;


    @Transactional
    public List<Record> getAllRecords()
    {

        return mainDao.getAllRecords();
    }

}
```

**Configuration:**

web.xml

```
<context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param> 

    <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Processes application requests -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

data.xml

```
<!-- Настраивает управление транзакциями с помощью аннотации @Transactional -->
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
    <!-- Менеджер транзакций -->
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="classpath:messages" />
        <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
    </bean>
    <!-- Настройки бина dataSource будем хранить в отдельном файле -->
    <bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer" p:location="/WEB-INF/jdbc.properties" />
    <!-- Непосредственно бин dataSource -->
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource" p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}"
        p:url="${jdbc.databaseurl}" p:username="${jdbc.username}" p:password="${jdbc.password}" />
    <!-- Настройки фабрики сессий Хибернейта -->
    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="configLocation">
            <value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
        </property>
        <property name="configurationClass">
            <value>org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration</value>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${jdbc.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.charSet">UTF-8</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

root-context.xml

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.wp.crud.dao"/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.wp.crud.controller"/>

<!--
 Файл с настройками ресурсов для работы с данными (Data Access Resources) 
-->
 <import resource="data.xml"/>
```

servlet-context.xml

```
<annotation-driven />

    <!-- Всю статику (изображения, css-файлы, javascript) положим в папку webapp/resources и замаппим их на урл вида /resources/** -->

    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
    <!-- Отображение видов на jsp-файлы, лежащие в папке /WEB-INF/views -->

    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>
    <!-- Файл с настройками контроллеров -->

    <beans:import resource="controllers.xml" />
```

controllers.xml

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.wp.crud.controller"/>
```

**P.S.**

Services located in controller package.

Comment: Post the full stacktrace instead of the snippet, together with the code that is trigger or using this object (which leads to this exception).

Comment: If you get this exception not whilst rendering your view but whilst retrieving data you have configured things wrong. I.e. `@Transactional `isn't scanned/processed in general this comes due to duplicate bean instances due to a wrong setup of component-scanning.

Comment: Your services aren't transactional (see the stacktrace). You are scanning for your services twice (once in the root-context.xml and once in the servlet-context.xml). Only the root-context has transactions defined and as AOP only applies to the ApplicationContext they are defined in your second instance isn't proxied and as such doesn't have transactions. Your root-context should scan for everything BUT `@Controller` and your controllers.xml only for `@Controllers`.

Comment: And where in stacktrace it could seen(that services aren't transactional)?

Comment: The fact that there is no call inside/through the `TransactionInterceptor` in the callstack. In fact when AOP is properly applied you would get a proxy->interceptor->interceptor->real-bean callstack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need, or want to use, the `OpenSessionInViewFilter` depends on your code. If you use your domain objects in your view and have lazy loading collections (the default) or references you will need this filter. By default the hibernate session is gone after finishing the `@Transactional`, however to perform lazy-loading a hibernate session is needed. The `OpenSessionInViewFilter` keeps the session(s) open until the view has been rendered.

If you don't have anything lazy or have specific queries/methods to retrieve all the data needed to render the view (i.e. force eager fetching of collection or objects with a HQL query) you don't need an `OpenSessionInViewFilter`.

So whether you need it or not depends on your use-case and technology choice.

The problem in your case is the fact that you are scanning the same package twice. This leads to duplicate bean instances (one in the `ContextLoaderListener` and one in the `DispatcherServlet` the first is the bean you want to use but due to the duplication the second is the one you get). The first is the one with transactions applied.

Change your component scan elements to the following

**root-context.xml**

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.wp.crud">
    <context:exclude-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller" />
</context:component-scan>
```

**controllers.xml**

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.wp.crud" use-default-filters="false">
    <context:include-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller" />
</context:component-scan>
```

This will make the `ContextLoaderListener` load everything BUT `@Controller` annotated beans and the `DispatcherServlet` loads only `@Controller` annotated beans.

Comment: And how does this change my answer? The fact remains it has to do with lazy loading (be it collections or not). As soon as the session is gone and yo need lazy loading in the view it breaks (and hence you need the `OpenSessionInViewFilter`).

Answer (score 0):

You should mark necessary methods with `@Transactional` to define where to start/end transactions.

In your application context you should define that it's annotation driven and define base package to scan. Thus Spring scans the packages and wraps methods marked as `@Transactional` with Proxies to start and commit/rollbacck transactions.

Comment: i think the point was if he must or must not use the OpenSessionInViewFilter

Comment: @EmanueleRighetto For me the question is about alternatives for the filter usage.

Comment: question about why in one way works without filter and in another way doesn't work without filter